# How to install Programs on Pi Without Pi Store

Tags: software-installation

I would like to install a number of programs on the Pi including Code Blocks, BlueJ (java IDE) and also install some things to get the sound working. However, I do not have internet access on the Pi and so I cannot use `apt-get` and get it from the Pi store. So, my question is, if possible what is the correct procedure for installing an application on the Pi from a USB flash drive? Is there a way to download a compressed file of the app from the Pi store and save it to a removable drive? Please, don't tell me to connect it to the internet because even though that is the easiest and best way to do this I cannot at the time. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: *"use `apt-get` **and** get it from the Pi store"* -> Dunno if you meant *or* there, but `apt-get` has nothing to do with the pi store.    It's a Debian tool for retrieving things from Debian style repositories, which Raspbian uses.   The Pi Store is something put together by the Pi Foundation; Raspbian is independent of this.

Comment: Ok..well as I was saying I don't have internet access so I can't do that.:-(

Comment: As long as you can download stuff somewhere else, you can install from a USB stick as per bobstro's answer (I don't know about the pi store in this regard, but I'm guessing there's actually nothing you need from there anyway).   The really PITA part is going to be making sure you have the right dependencies.   You can figure them out from looking in the `.deb` files, although it is a bit tedious and complicated (ask about this on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to get access to the packages somehow, so the first question is how do you plan on doing that without Internet access?

If you can find the appropriate .deb file, you could copy it over and install it with `dpkg -i debfilename.deb`.

Comment: The top level of the Raspbian repository (wheezy and jessie) [is here](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/); most stuff is alphabetized under "main".   It's all `.deb` files.   BlueJ is not packaged there (Code Blocks is), but there's a Raspbian specific version right on [their front page](http://www.bluej.org/).

Comment: I wan't to download the .deb files...I think thats what I need...in order to put on a USB stick and unpack and install on pi. I don't want parts of the OS but programs such as Code Blocks. The link above I don't understand...where are the apps? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @NULL There is no distinction between parts of the OS and user programs, in terms of packaging. Both OS components such as inits, daemons, kernel images, etc, *and* applications such as CodeBlocks are available from the repository.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to install packages on machines without internet access.

If you have another computer (that has internet) and an ethernet patch cable, you can simply share your computer's internet connection to your RPi.

One example to get internet to your RPi is described [here](http://blog.arvixe.com/how-to-share-wireless-connection-via-ethernet-cable-in-ubuntu-to-any-device/).

If you either cannot or do not want to get internet to your Pi, you'd have to download each of the packages's precompiled ARM binaries or their source and all of their dependencies, then install them using <kbd>dpkg -i package.deb</kbd> or the usual build instructions <kbd>./configure && make && make install</kbd>.

To get the source, you can use <kbd>apt-get source package-name</kbd> to download it to your machine and then transfer it via external storage, or you could find their precompiled binaries elsewhere online.

Comment: Great info! So, could I follow your procedure for any file with a .deb extension?

Comment: @NULL Yes, as long as you also have all dependencies for that deb already installed, or you provide them on that flash drive.